# Function name in stack trace of SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, spidermonkey

I'm using the SpiderMonkey engine 1.8 and I'm unhappy with the way it creates the stack trace. We occasionally receive auto-generated function names in JavaScript-files from the server, which aren't really readable. On the client side I have access to other functionalities that allow me to make them more readable to humans.

Does anyone know how SpiderMonkey builds one line of a stack trace? Is there a way I can influence this?

- The `name`-property of a function is readonly
- [WebKit's `displayName`](http://www.alertdebugging.com/2009/04/29/building-a-better-javascript-profiler-with-webkit/) doesn't seem to work in SpiderMonkey (yet)

---

**EDIT**: I took a look at the [source of SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Getting_SpiderMonkey_source_code) and, whow, I don't know if it's just me, but that C++ code is close to unreadable. Well, I don't have that much experience with C++, but it's damn hard to find a way through all those files. I found no way...

So, please, it's up to you :).

Comment: @Incognito: I saw this file, but I can't find anything useful. E.g., there's `getFunctionPrivate()`, which calls `getPrivate()`, which I can't find.

Comment: I just filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706324

Comment: @cdleary: Thanks! Please keep us informed if something is happening. I will check every now and then... But, I guess this is something that won't be in there before version 1.9.

Comment: @sjngm: I'd recommend CC'ing yourself on that bug to get timely updates, don't count on me. :-) I also asked specifically to see if there is anything currently in place to do this that I don't know about.

Comment: I checked the issue on the Mozilla-site and they closed it. So this isn't going to happen. Aww. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the stacktrace and manipulate it, you could use [stackinfo](https://github.com/fresheneesz/stackinfo) to get parsed stacktrace information, then rebuild the stacktrace how you want to build it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but in our project we are not allowed to use external libraries. Due to that I won't do any tests with our browser. But maybe someone else finds it useful.

Comment: Is this a school project or something?

Comment: School is like 20 years past ;) No, it's a browser in an embedded environment with limited amount of memory, strict source control and all.